# Linux shell script erroroing out due to /usr/bin/sh

Tags: linux, shell, unix, installation, redhat

I am trying to run a shell script on redhat linux to install an app. I am getting an error saying /usr/bin.sh: bad interpreter: no such file or directory.

In the shell script the script begins with:

```
#!/usr/bin/shBUILD_ID=$1.....
```

I am just trying to understand what the path at the begining of the line is for? Is that a directory it looks for to deploy the app?

Thanks

Comment: Your title, text, and pasted code use 3 different spellings. Do you think maybe spelling it correctly actually matters, and no one can possibly tell you what's wrong if you lie about what you actually have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line should be `#!/usr/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/sh` if its a shell script.

If the first line are `#!/usr/bin/sh` then try to see if /usr/bin/sh exist and you with `ls -l /usr/bin/sh`

If you cant find `sh` then your system are in a bad stat.

Comment: I can't find sh in the usr/bin directory - there is ssh though

Answer (score 2):

The `#!` is a magic number that tells the kernel that the file is an excutable script.
The string immediately following the `#!` is the path to an interpreter that is called to read and execute the contents of the file. In the line

```
#!/ust/bin/shBUILD_ID=$1.....
```

the interpreter is `/ust/bin/shBUILD_ID=$1....`. The interpreter is read directly, with no shell variable substition, so it will look for a file exactly as you specified (including the equal sign, dollar, dots etc.). If the interpreter you specified is not found, a default shell issues an error message, and yours looks totally wrong. Try `#!/bin/sh`.
If the interpreter string is followed by a space and then some arguments, those arguments are passed to the interpeter when it is invoked.

See for example http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang